# Remove block() method from reactive code response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I tried this client into Spring Cloud Gateway:

```
  @Autowired
  public WebClient webClient;
    
  public Mono<Response> getPayload(.......) {

    // Create custom headers
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.add(.......);

    // Create the request body
    MultiValueMap<String, String> requestBody = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    requestBody.add(....);

    // Make the POST request
    Mono<Response> responseMono = webClient.method(HttpMethod.POST)
            .uri(........)
            .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(headers))
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(requestBody))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Response.class);

    // Convert the Mono to a custom Java object
    Mono<Response> customObjMono = responseMono.map(customObject -> {
      // Convert the CustomObject to CustomObj
      Response customObj = new Response();
      // Perform any necessary mapping or transformation
      customObj.setAccessToken(customObject.getAccessToken());
      return customObj;
    });

    return customObjMono;
  }

      Response token = client.getPayload(........).block();
```

But I get error at this `.block()` code:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-4
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.filter.reactive.ServerWebExchangeContextFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
```

What is the proper way to implement this without `.block()` method?

PS I tried also:

Mono token = client.getPayload(........);

```
  token.subscribe(transformedToken -> {
    // Handle the transformedToken object here
    UaaToken plainJavaObject = transformedToken; // Assign transformedToken to a variable of type UaaToken
    // You can return plainJavaObject or perform any other desired operations
  });
```

But it's not clear how to get plainJavaObject from this `subscribe` code block.

EDIT:

How I can simplify this code:

```
public Mono<ResponseObject> processData() {
    // Perform your non-blocking operation and return a Mono
    return Mono.just(ResponseObject);
}


      AtomicReference<ResponseObject> plainJavaObject = new AtomicReference<>();
      processData().subscribe(transformedToken -> {
        // Handle the transformedToken object here
        plainJavaObject.set(transformedToken);
      });
      ResponseObject responseObject = plainJavaObject.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Summary

`getPayload`  method  has Mono which is non-blocking method and reactivie programing  , so when you invoke reactor method like mono flux ,please  in mention  your current thread .  last  , reactive program is unnecessary that get the javaobject ,  just provide some applier or function for compose and invoke .

below is how to get the object and use subscribe to do next step . Alternatively, you can write your hander in  `doOnNext` instead of `subscribe()`

```java
public Mono<String> processData() {
    // Perform your non-blocking operation and return a Mono
    return Mono.just("Data");
}


// below is function for compose 
public void doSomething() {
    processData().subscribe(result -> {
        System.out.println(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added code how to get the Java object. Any simple way to get the data?

Comment: @ Peter Penzov
 as  perviously , use block ()   , through block thread model  you can  get  object